# Caffeine Cache - instance object in get method

Tags: java, caching, caffeine-cache

I have a service that using Caffeine Cache to store another class and I use the 'id' field in this class as the key.

Here's a simple example:

```
class MyService {
    Cache<Long, MyObj> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder().build();

    public void doSomething(long id) {
        MyObj myObj = cache.get(id, k -> new MyObj(id));
    }
}

class MyObj {
    long id;
    // other fields below...

    public MyObj(long id) {
        log.info("init complete. id {}", id);
    }
}
```

My understanding of cache.get is that if the key does not exist, it will execute the function provided as the second parameter and store its result back into the cache.
So, when I retrieve the value for the key for the first time, it will instantiate MyObj and display the log "init complete. id = 1" (assuming the id is 1) on the console.

But strangely, my console displays "init complete" three times at different time points.

```
Dec 19, 2023 @ 00:01:00.665 2023-12-19 00:01:00.664 INFO 11 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.i.l.c.service.MyService : init complete. id = 63326

Dec 19, 2023 @ 00:00:49.833 2023-12-19 00:00:49.832 INFO 14 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.i.l.c.service.MyService : init complete. id = 63326

Dec 19, 2023 @ 00:00:37.266 2023-12-19 00:00:37.266 INFO 14 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.i.l.c.service.MyService : init complete. id = 63326
```

I would like to understand why this situation is occurring.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same service class instance? You could log at the constructor or log the identity hash code of the class and cache instance

Comment: MyService has the Service annotation, and I haven't made any adjustments regarding the Bean configuration, so I assume it should be a singleton ..?

Comment: I don’t know modern Spring, it’s just a gotcha that I’ve seen before. If you use a ConcurrentHashMap with computeIfAbsent, you’ll have the same bug. Usually that’s something with your setup

Comment: Can't reproduce the behavior with this code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea to reproduce the behavior too...

Comment: Try printing `cache` or `this` (in the service). If it's really a singleton it should show the same output each time.